# Unable to bind API data to this.setState in React JS using fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React JS and I have a problem in displaying data in table through fetch API call. Am able to get JSON data but unable to bind the data to this.State object. It always throws the following error.

**index.bundle.js:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: users is not defined**

May I know what am doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Badge, Row, Col, Card, CardHeader, CardBlock, Table, Pagination, PaginationItem, PaginationLink} from "reactstrap";

class Users extends Component {


  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state={users:[]};
  }

  componentDidMount(){

     fetch('http://some_ip_address/api/subuserlist',{
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'filterfield': 'group_id',
          'filtervalue': 'random_filter_value'
        }
     }).then(result=>result.json())
       .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);           //able to print data
          this.setState({users:data});
          console.log(users);        //unable to print users
       }.bind(this))    
       .catch(function(error) {
         // If there is any error you will catch them here
       });   
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="animated fadeIn">
         <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Combined All Table
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBlock className="card-body">
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                   {this.state.users && this.state.users.map(function(users) {                  
                      return (
                          <tr>
                              <td>{users.firstName}</td>
                          </tr>
                        )

                    })}</tbody>
                </table>
              </CardBlock>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
   );
 }
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: You don't have `users` variable defined. You only have users in your state. Try `console.log(this.state.users)` instead.

Comment: even doing this.state.users there might not work because of async behavior of setState

Comment: Yes, it probably won't show up immediately (the array will still be empty). But it won't throw an error and it should get the correct results when using it for rendering.

Comment: I tried using this.state.users but it still throws the same error ... Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `users` isn't defined in the scope of your callback function (in Fetch).  Replace `console.log(users);` with `console.log(this.state.users);`.  Also, you're gonna have to change your callback from a regular anonymous function to an arrow function, otherwise `this` won't refer to your class, it'll refer to the callback function.

```
  componentDidMount(){
     fetch('http://some_ip_address/api/subuserlist',{
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'filterfield': 'group_id',
          'filtervalue': 'random_filter_value'
        }
     }).then(result=>result.json())
       .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);           //able to print data
          this.setState({
            users:data
          }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.users); // This will be fired after setState has completed.
          });
       })    
       .catch(function(error) {
         // If there is any error you will catch them here
       });   
  }
```

Comment: I tried your method and it still throws the same error. Any help?

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is where your error is occurring?

Comment: hey wait, am not getting error now but unable to render table... Any corrections at table code? Also am not able to print any data using this.state.users